# Text box to variable parse

Tags: c#, parsing

just to warn everyone, I barely know what I'm doing here so go easy, returning to writing some code and it's been a while.

Basically I have a windows form c# app and want to read a string input from a text box and assign it to a variable as a number. Nothing I've tried is working, taking the first line "double m" and attempting to parse it, visual studio does not even see my text box name when I start typing txt, nothing appears on the list.

Does this have something to do with where I'm trying to write the variables?

```
namespace Incline_Impact
{
    public partial class Incline : Form
    {
        double m = double.Parse(txtMass.Text); //mass in kg
        double g; //gravity 9.81 default
        float h; //height in meters
        double u; //coefficient of friction, 0.18 steel-steel
        double angle; //9.92 angle for our machine
        double sl; //sensor length
    
        public Incline()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void Calculate()
        {
        }

        private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Put the `double m = double.Parse(txtMass.Text);` part inside the `btnCalculate_Click` method.

Comment: Also look into `double.TryParse` method; don't trust input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write code in button click event

```
private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   double number;
   bool result = double.TryParse(txtMass.Text, out number);
}
```